# Bitlocked VHDX and VM import

Tags: hyper-v, vhd, bitlocker

I have a Windows VM with two drives: OS(C) and DATA(D).
The DATA drive is encrypted with bitlocker.
Upon restarting the VM, Windows would ask me to "unlock the DATA drive" prompting for the key.

I have now exported this VM, and imported it back on another Hyper-V server.
Upon restarting the VM, it doesn't ask the question anymore.
Disk Manager reveals the drive just appears unpartitioned.

What's going on here? 
Is it even possible at all to export a machine where one or more of the drives has been encrypted with bitlocker?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you exported and imported _both_ disks?

Comment: Yes, both. If I didn't, the 2nd wouldn't even show up in disk management - which it does. It just appears uninitialized, a raw unpartitioned disk.

Comment: Most likely you didn't export/import the VM correctly. Try again. I have created a test disk on Win 8.1 VM, bitlocked it. Then exported VM and imported it as a copy - with a new identifier. I was able to unlock the disk with password no problems. Moreover, I connected it to a totally different VM and was able to unlock it no problems too.